# Getting TypeError: undefined is not a function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

on my site, i currently have a modal that is opened.  when the user clicks on the button to close the modal, it calls:

```
$scope.hideModal = function(modalId) {
    angular.element(modalId).hide();
    DatabaseService.updateDB();
};
```

DatabaseService is a seperate .js class that contains methods to make read/changes to the database

```
var _updateDashboardInterstitialPromoDbService = function(){
//code to update the database
}
```

When I run my site, the modal closes successfully, but i see an error in my console:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at h.$scope.hideModal

How do I resolve this typeerror to successfully call the function to update my database?

Here's my ModalCtrl.js

```
'use strict';
var DashboardCtrl =
[
    '$scope',
    'DashboardInterstitialPromoService',
    function ($scope, DashboardInterstitialPromoService) {
        $scope.hideModal = function(modalId) {
        angular.element(modalId).hide();
        DatabaseService.updateDB();
    };
];
```

Here's my DatabaseService.js:

```
'use strict';
var databaseService = angular.module('database.service', ['ngResource']);
databaseService.factory('DatabaseService',
[
    function() {
    var _updateDB = function(){
        //stuff to update db
    };
    return {updateDB: _updateDB};
}]);
```

Comment: What is `DatabaseService` and how are you getting it in to your controller?

Comment: DatabaseService is a completely seperate .js file.  In my controller, MainCtrl.js, I injected DatabaseService.js.  So it looks something like: var MainCtrl = ['DatabaseService', function (DatabaseService) { etc.

Comment: So it's a registered factory / service? You're really going to have to add some more code to your question. Show where you define `DatabaseService` and its `updateDB` method. Show how you're injecting it into your controller

Comment: Also see that you have the code file hooked up to the parent html page. Usually done through a <script> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included `DatabaseService` in your controller. It should look something like this-

```
'use strict';
var DashboardCtrl =
[
    '$scope',
    'DashboardInterstitialPromoService',
     'DatabaseService',
    function ($scope, DashboardInterstitialPromoService,DatabaseService) {
        $scope.hideModal = function(modalId) {
        angular.element(modalId).hide();
        DatabaseService.updateDB();
    };
];
```